# How can I expand data while fetching it in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am trying to convert time data into JavaScript time while selecting it.
JavaScript time is unix time multiplied by 1000.

I am already getting unix time using this Query:

```
SELECT date_part('epoch',time) as unixtime FROM mytable;
```

Is there a way to modify this query to append "000" to each result? Or get it to JavaScript time any other smart way.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You pretty much answer your own question in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by 1000:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from current_timestamp) * 1000;
```

or in your form:

```
SELECT date_part('epoch',time) * 1000 as unixtime FROM mytable;
```

If you want it rounded to an integer just:

```
SELECT CAST(round(date_part('epoch',time) * 1000) AS bigint) as unixtime FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Just one more concern, does the multiplying operation take a lot of time? but, Thank you, that did the trick!

Comment: @PhilippWerminghausen Multiplying a float or double is an insanely fast hardware level operation. If you were multiplying `numeric` it'd be quite a lot slower, but `date_part` (`extract`) returns a double. If in doubt, always test and see.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply multiplying it by `1000` like this?

```
SELECT date_part('epoch',time)*1000 as unixtime FROM mytable
```